# nginx staging rewrite http to https with port number

Tags: nginx, 400

I'm getting a 400 bad request.

This is the config code. file: staging.rewrites

```
if ($scheme = http) {
   return 301 https://$host:[port]$request_uri;
}
```

Does anyone know if this is a valid rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where is your config file, although, I'd rather use the following lines in your 80 port to rewrite requests to port 443:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name YOURSERVER_DOMAIN;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.http.log detailed;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.http.log notice;

    location / {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: This is the correct answer. I had to use the http port 80. I was using the https port. like this www.hostname.com:443/request_uri.

Answer (score 1):

This is the preferred way to do http -> https redirect in nginx:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```